# Get current page title in observer (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, helper, page

Is their any way we can get current page title in magento 2 ?

Comment: Is their any way i can use di method & achieve the same ?

Answer (score 2):

Quick but not recommended

You can call the following directly in your file:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$title = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title');
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**Via DI**

```
protected $_pageTitle;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Title $pageTitle
) {
    $this->_pageTitle = $pageTitle;
}


public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->_pageTitle->getShort();
}
```

Comment: Is their any way i can use di method & achieve the same ?

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal Please check my answer and if it works give thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

You can set and get page title using observer like below

> Step 1: Please create events.xml file under
> PackageName/CustomTitle/etc/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="layout_generate_blocks_after">
       <observer name="hideorders" instance="PackageName\CustomTitle\Observer\Currentpagetitle" />
   </event>
</config>
```

> Step 2: Please create Currentpagetitle.php file under
> PackageName/CustomTitle/Observer/

```
<?php
namespace PackageName\CustomTitle\Observer;
 
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
 
class Currentpagetitle implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_pageConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $pageConfig
    ) {
        $this->_pageConfig = $pageConfig;   
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getData('layout');
        $pageMainTitle = $layout->getBlock('page.main.title');
        if ($pageMainTitle)
        {
            $oldTitle = $pageMainTitle->getPageTitle();//Get current page title

            //Set custom meta title and page title like below
            $this->_pageConfig->getTitle()->set($oldTitle. __('- Custom Title'));
            $pageMainTitle->setPageTitle(
                $oldTitle
                . __('- Custom Title')
            );
        }
    }
}
```